# How to open a generated pdf in electron?

Tags: pdf, electron, pdfmake

im using Electron, i need to open a new window with a pdf generated with pdfmake.js, im trying this

```
    pdf = pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition);
    pdf.getDataUrl(function(dataUrl){
        win.loadURL(dataUrl);
    });
```

this just open a new window and download the pdf

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new `BrowserWindow` and load the data URL. Setting `webPreferences.plugins` to `true` is crucial.

```
pdf.getDataUrl((url) => {
  const win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    title: '',
    webPreferences: {
      plugins: true,
    },
  });
  win.loadURL(url);
});
```